# Wysiwyg javascript framework (build a builder)

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

Looking for a javascript framework that allows to build an *online* web component that builds other web components. I'll clarify: thinking about building a drag-n-drop/wysiwyg web application that produces javascript pages/documents/dialogs etc.

I know that I can start from jQuery, however, if anyone can recommend a higher-level framework that will allow to build a "builder" (with toolbars, drag-n-drop etc) - please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) was designed especially for this.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/

ExtJS...

Here's an example "builder" app: http://www.projectspace.nl/